# Converting observational data stored in a 2D data frame to a 3D array in R

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I am trying to produce a 3D array from a 2D data frame in R and could really use some help. So far, I haven't found a solution to this problem from similar questions that have been posted previously.

My input data are available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f8td34mpzgpvgh/example_data.csv?dl=0, and they resemble the following basic structure: I have 14 sites (i.e. `Field`) with 6 replicates each (i.e. `Replicate`) in which a subset of 32 subjects (i.e. columns of species codes: `AMGO`, `BASW`, etc.) were counted when present in a survey.

A subset of the input data looks like so:

```
example_data[1:5, 1:5]

       Field Replicate AMGO BASW BHCO
1   Brinkman         1    2    0    0
72  Brinkman         2   10    0    0
190 Brinkman         3    6    0    0
283 Brinkman         4    0    0    0
342 Brinkman         5    2    1    0
```

I'd like to reformat these input data to resemble a 3D array (i.e. 14 sites x 6 replicates x 32 subjects), as exemplified below with the `AMGO` species:

```
, ,  = AMGO

            1 2 3 4 5 6
Brinkman    0 0 0 0 0 0
Clara       0 0 0 0 0 0
Esckelson   0 0 0 0 0 0
GarnerEast  0 0 0 0 0 0
GarnerWest  0 0 0 0 0 0
KHess       0 0 0 0 0 0
Lounsbury   0 0 0 0 0 0
McCallum    0 0 0 0 0 0
Pomeroy     0 0 0 0 0 0
Sattelberg  0 0 0 0 0 0
THess       0 0 0 0 0 0
Turner      0 0 0 0 0 0
VollmarEast 0 0 0 0 0 0
VollmarWest 0 0 0 0 0 0

...
```

Note that, in the solution, many of the zeroes above would likely be replaced by non-zero counts when `AMGO` (and other species) was (were) actually encountered during a survey.

Please let me know if there's anything I need to clarify, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `reshape()` function from base R. I'm applying the function to each of the subject columns and creating a list of reshaped dataframes.

```
df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Shrivatav\\Downloads\\example_data.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")

# Extract subject columns 
list.of.cols <- colnames(df)[3:34]

# Function for reshaping
func.for.reshaping <- function(column){

  # Subset the data, keep only Field, replicate and the column input in the 
  # function
  to.keep <- c("Field", "Replicate", column)
  subset.df <- df[to.keep]
  # reshape from long to wide
  reshaped.df <- reshape(subset.df, idvar = "Field", timevar = "Replicate", direction = "wide")
  return(reshaped.df)
}

# Apply the function over all subject columns, reulting
# in a list of dataframes
list.of.reshaped.dfs <- lapply(list.of.cols, func.for.reshaping)

# Name the list for easy access
names(list.of.reshaped.dfs) <- list.of.cols
```

You can access the elements of the list like: `list.of.reshaped.dfs$AMGO` and so forth.

Comment: Thank you, @Vishesh Shrivastav! This solution is very helpful, and I sincerely appreciate your time and expertise.